# Add hour as a parameter to Specials in Opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

Opencart has a function to set special price on items. But this special price is set with date start/date end. I'm wondering if anyone can help me to set also end hour for same promotions? Now they end at midnight.

Thanks!

Comment: At midnight, the day changes. So I don't understand why you need to set a specific time. Assuming it's based on your server time, then I don't see what change needs to be made to implement this. For example, today is 11/11. At midnight, the day changes to 11/12. So changing according to date is how you'd work with something like this. The only reason you'd want to manipulate the exact time is if something ends at 7pm in the evening.

Comment: Well, I need to set a promotion that will end at noon. But I'm not sure that changing server time is an option :)
Also, it's possible to login and remove promotion manually, but here comes the problem with a countdown timer that will show 12 hours and 1 minute left at 11:59... which will not be true and will mislead the customers.

Comment: Ok, i get it now. Your original question didn't specify "noon." It was a bit vague, sorry. It made it sound like it expired at midnight. So to clarify, you want it to expire at noon-time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you have tried (which would've helped to see your code), so I will just point you in the right direction since there are a number of files you need to make edits to here:

First, in your database, when you go to your oc_product_special table, you can either:
a) add two new fields with the "type" set as datetime, or...
b) modify the types on on your date_start and date_ended from "date" to "datetime" instead.

If you don't know what you're doing (or you don't feel comfortable editing the table of your database), I would go with option a so you have a fall-back at least in case you need to restore a backup. Name them something similar like `timedate_start` and `timedate_end`

Next, you then need to edit the following files (I think I have all of them). Look for any lines of code with "special", and modify them accordingly. **Beware** that you may need to make multiple edits in multiple places on some of these files, **and** you will also need to edit for the datetime format (and not just just swapping names out):

```
admin/controller/catalog/product.php
admin/model/catalog/product.php
admin/view/catalog/product_form.tpl
catalog/model/catalog/product.php
system/library/cart/cart.php file
```

Another way to go on about all of this is to add two fields with type "time" separately, but that may end up involving more coding work on your end to join the variables together. That's my opinion though. It's easier to just use the datetime type since you can still use it for specials that you may want to run all day or for several days if you choose to.

Comment: Thank you very much for these hints. I'll try to implement it with additional columns in the database.

Comment: My pleasure. There are a lot of edits here. If you have trouble with any of them though specify which ones, and I can take a look further.

Comment: Hello, i tried according to your guide.. now the "Special" tab shows the format in "YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". But, "HH:MM:SS" is always set to "00:00:00" and the special price is not shown even when i set in directly in the database. Even if i change it through the Special tab, the time is set to 00:00:00. Help please?